# Probability of random subsets of the same size intersecting

Tags: probability

$A$ and $B$ are subsets drawn uniformly from a set $C$, such that $|A|=|B|=a$ and $|C|=n$.
For what $a$ is the probability of $A\cap B \ne \varnothing$ equal to  $50\%$?

I figured that if $|A|=a$ and $|B|=b$ then the probability that there will be no intersection is 
$$\frac{(n-a)!(n-b)!}{n!(n-a-b)!}$$
and for this special case, 
$$\frac{(n-a)!(n-a)!}{n!(n-2a)!}$$
If we expand it, we get:
$$\prod_{i=0}^{a-1}{\left(1-\frac{a}{n-i}\right)}$$
and I wasn't able to go further from here to solve when is it equal to $0.5$

Comment: If $\frac{a}{n-1}$ is small, you can take the log on both sides, and use the approximation of $\log(1-x) \approx -x$ for $x$ small, together with $\log( ab ) = \log(a) + \log (b)$ to obtain $\sum_{i=0}^{a-1} \frac{a}{n-i} \le \log 2$. Then solving this for $a$ gets an approximate answer for large $n$, provided that $\frac{a}{n-i}$ stays small.

Comment: @Hetebrij I expect $a$ to be somewhere around $\sqrt{n}$. Maybe another solution path may lead to an exact solution, which seems to be $\sqrt{\ln 2}\sqrt{n}$

Comment: @Hetebrij Asymptotically, not for exact integers

Comment: Asympotitcally, the approximation of $\log(1 -x) \approx -x$ is justified as $\frac{\sqrt{n}}{n - \sqrt{n}} \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we use Stirling's Approximation, that is $n!\sim\sqrt{2\pi n}\frac{n^n}{e^n}$, we get that
$$
\frac{\binom{n-a}{a}}{\binom{n}{a}}\sim\frac{\left(1-\frac an\right)^{2n-2a+1}}{\left(1-\frac{2a}n\right)^{n-2a+1/2}}
$$
Using $\left(1+\frac xn\right)^n=e^x\left(1+O\left(\frac{x^2}n\right)\right)$, we get
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\left(1-\frac an\right)^{2n-2a+1}}{\left(1-\frac{2a}n\right)^{n-2a+1/2}}
&=\frac{\left(1-\frac{2a}n+\frac{a^2}{n^2}\right)^{n-a+1/2}}{\left(1-\frac{2a}n\right)^{n-2a+1/2}}\\
&=\left[1+\frac{\frac{a^2}{n^2}}{1-\frac{2a}n}\right]^{\,n}\frac{\left(1-\frac{2a}n\right)^{2a}}{\left(1-\frac{2a}n+\frac{a^2}{n^2}\right)^a}\left[\frac{1-\frac{2a}n+\frac{a^2}{n^2}}{1-\frac{2a}n}\right]^{1/2}\\
&=\left[1+\frac{a^2}{n^2}+O\left(\frac{a^3}{n^3}\right)\right]^n\left(1-\frac{2a}n+O\left(\frac{a^2}{n^2}\right)\right)^a\left[1+O\left(\frac{a^2}{n^2}\right)\right]\\
&=e^{-a^2/n}\left(1+O\left(\frac{a^3}{n^2}\right)\right)
\end{align}
$$
Finding the $a$ so that this is approximately $\frac12$, we get
$$
a\sim\sqrt{n\log(2)}
$$

Comment: I'd be very greatful if you elaborated on the details; what form of Sterling's approximation and in what way did you apply the approximation of $e^x$

Comment: Thanks, but I still don't understand the first approximation with Sterling.

Comment: @NightRa: use Stirling and $\binom{n}{a}=\frac{n!}{(n-a)!\,a!}$ to get the first approximation.

Comment: @BCLC Stirling itself I inderstand :) just had issues with manipulating it algebraicly to fit nicely like that, but got it figured out already

Comment: @NightRa: is there something that you don't like?

Comment: I've found a much cleaner proof, but you definitely deserve the acceptance :)

Comment: You can add that as an answer. I'd be interested in seeing it.